# How to calculate clipper new battery charging time

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, nimh

I'm replacing batteries on a hair clipper following [this tutorial](https://www-ifixit-com.translate.goog/Guide/BaByliss+Titanium+T83a+Battery+Replacement/139196?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=wapp). New batteries have higher capacity than the original ones :

- old batteries : 2x BYD AAA NiMH 1.2V 600 mAh
- new batteries : 2x Eneloop AAA NiMH 1.2V 800 mAh (5th gen, BK-4MCDE)

My questions is : **What is the impact of this capacity difference on the charging time ?**

---

The [clipper manual](https://www.modesdemploi.fr/babyliss/e702xte/mode-d-emploi?p=7) is not clear about the charging time of the original batteries :

> To obtain and maintain the longest battery autonomy possible, allow it
> to charge for 16 hours before using it for the first time and then
> approximately every three months.

And 16 hours seems to be a very long charging time for these small cells.

### Details

**AC/DC power adapter**

```
MODEL NO : HKA-024100EC-230
PRI. : 230V~50Hz 40mA
SEC. : 2.4V DC 1000mA 2.4VA
```

Despite what is written on the adapter, I measured 4.5V on the output jack using a [cheap multimeter](https://media.adeo.com/marketplace/LMIT/81979044/1798789.pdf), not 2.4V. I don't know if this measurement is relevant however.

**Clipper**

You can see the clipper internals here :

- https://a.allegroimg.com/s1024/0c64e1/d0c4a6554c439c19f1bbe966978a
- https://a.allegroimg.com/s1024/0ca896/f6aca8134308bc966f8d2d8a898b
- https://a.allegroimg.com/s1024/0cd096/8cf663ba404880ffc5e9c9299ce0

And I also tried to draw the whole circuit, I think it's accurate :
[image: E702XTE circuit]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The capacity of the new battery is (800/600 = 1.33) 33% larger. So the charging will take about 33% longer. This calculation only works when charging at low current, say less than 0.5C but that is likely the case here.